# Why has this edit been rejected?

Tags: discussion, scope, suggested-edits

I submitted this [edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12224). I think it adds a better example of the discussed situation. The example is more traceable as it featured during a World Cup Qualifier game so it would be easier to identify the players, the date, the referee etc... in short, I think it is a better source.

Maybe it was a bad idea to edit a high ranked user's post, and I'm sorry for that. But the reason given is

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I don't think it deviates from the original intent, I justed added another source to enforce the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion (which matters quite a lot as it's my answer - we're a lot more tolerant of radical edits to questions than to answers), I was happy with the example that's there. In particular, as far as I can see from the clip you've linked to, I don't see the player receive a *second yellow card*, only a red.

(And for what it's worth, I'm not a moderator).

Comment: A few seconds later on the video, a flashback slow motion at [6:02](https://youtu.be/eUglB-QNkvU?t=362) we can see the referee holding the yellow card which induced the red card.

Comment: I also think my example is relevant because it has another yellow card reason. The first example, the reason is removing the shirt. The example I suggested, the reason is taking too much time to quit the pitch.

Comment: If you think it's a great example, you're always welcome to post your own answer :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I'm not sure how the OP's own answer would be any more useful. It would be your answer with a different example.

Comment: I don't think it would need answer just for this. I just wanted to improve the already correct and accepted answer.

Comment: But my question is still unresolved: why "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.".

Comment: Philip stated that they saw no second yellow card in the new example, which would mean from their perspective, it doesn't match the intent of *showing a red card given after the second yellow card while being substituted* at all.

Comment: @Nij the example I added shows a player receiving a 2nd yellow card while leaving the pitch hence a red card.

Comment: ***"... from their perspective, it doesn't match the intent ..."*** - it doesn't matter if the video showed fifty yellow cards, when the viewer only watches the part showing the red card because that was the only section they were asked to watch.